# Windows 10: command line equivalent to "file ownership: personal"

Tags: windows-10, efs

I am using windows 10 (pro, 1909, 18363.836) on a surface pro 3 and I have my home directory encrypted with EFS. I would like to make a subfolder that is not encrypted.

- `cipher /d /s:folder` does nothing (folder still shows with green text in Explorer)
- Explorer right-click -> properties -> advanced -> untick the encrypted attribute gives an "error applying permissions"
- Explorer right-click -> File Ownership -> Personal seems to be the only way to remove the encrypted attribute.

I would like a command-line command to encrypt/decrypt files and folders. Possibly there is some switch to disable this "file ownership" business so I can use `cipher` again?

Comment: Not sure you can do it the way you want. Let others bring their own input here, but knowing how permissions work in Windows (all versions, more or less), I don't think it's possible *quite that way*.

Comment: The right-click menu you mention does not exist on my system can you provide a screenshot?

Comment: Didier: it used to work like that (Win 7 ultimate), and I think also when I first had Win 10; I think it's an update a year or so ago that broke it IIRC. @Ramhound: it's the first one on this page: https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/87475-add-remove-efs-file-ownership-context-menu-windows-10-a.html

Comment: @Bristol - I suspect all you are doing is setting the Share permissions on the file.  Can you confirm?

Comment: @Ramhound no, I don't think it's the same thing. Setting ownership to personal removes the encryption signifiers (green text, padlock icon) in Explorer, and the "encrypted" advanced attribute is no longer ticked in the folder's properties afterwards. The ACLs don't seem to have changed (I'm the only user except for built-in administrator on the machine, so there's no-one to share with really).

Comment: @Bristol - Yes;  I took at look at the registry script after my comment, and it does appear, that the files are being decrypted.  *I don't know how to reverse whatever that context menu does since it isn't a standard operation.*  A possible workaround would be to avoid encrypting your entire user profile, and only encrypt specific folders, but I have never used cipher utility more than a handful of times.

Comment: Isn't standard? It came with a windows update I think. Defnitely a Microsoft thing if tenforums is correct - they make it sound like it's built into Win10.